# Understand Sharding in MYSQL cluster with different storage engines

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

After I study in MySQL, I learn that there are popular two types of the cluster which are InnoDB and NDB. I want to discuss is about **sharding**.

The InnoDB cluster does not really distribute data by partitioning to each node. It just partitions the data locally (each node has the same copied data by replication), while the NDB cluster does. Furthermore, the downside of the InnoDB cluster is application level partitioning which means have to decide which PARTITION is going to use.
e.g. SELECT * FROM table PARTITION (p1).

Do I understand it right?

Comment: Please clarify...  Are you focusing on what happens with `PARTITION` _in a single server_?  Or are you interested in discussing what happens _across multiple servers_?

Comment: I am interest in what happens across multiple servers. 
I want to make sure if  InnoDB "cluster" can achieve sharding. If it could. How it works?

Comment: Now that we have cleared up the terminology, `PARTITION(p1)` has nothing to do with "sharding", only with "partitioning".  I embellished my Answer.

Comment: Thank you for both of you. It really proves my concept. I will hands-on the MongoDb rather than Mysql. I think MogoDb is supposed to make me feel more familiar this topic and the underhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:  InnoDB Cluster does not provide sharding.  (That is, splitting table(s) across multiple servers.)  NDB does.

Long Answer:

For any "ordinary" database, simply use InnoDB.  Perhaps only 1% of MySQL users "need" NDB.  Don't even consider it until you have discussed your application with someone familiar with both NDB and InnoDB.

Perhaps only 1% of InnoDB users ever "need" `PARTITIONing`.  When I encounter that in this forum, I usually spend time explaining why they would actually be better off *without* Partitioning.  Again, let's hear what your application is.

"Partitioning" is often confused with "Sharding".  For MySQL, Sharding, not partitioning, involves putting different rows on different physical servers.  Sharding is also a 1% feature.  Again, let's discuss whether it is even relevant.

I am happy to discuss any of the above in more detail, but only in a more focused context.

In general, it is best to prototype in InnoDB, grow the dataset until you can see a real need for NDB / Partitioning / Sharding.  By then, you will have a better feel for which you need and how to do it (server topology, partition / shard key, etc)

Comment: I saw some books using Partitioning term to represent partitions was placed to non-sharing cluster. 
It is quite confused :) There are other terms called a vnod  in Cassandra, Sharding in MongoDB. 

You are saying that Innodb cluster doesn’t have
Sharding (stick with your term). As I know Sharding is essential for a distributed architecture. so Mysql is maybe not good for scalability?

Comment: One problem is that "partitioning" means different things depending on context. In discussions of the CAP theorem, the P is for partition-tolerance but this is really close to what the MySQL market refers to as sharding. This adds to confusion.

Comment: It is why I don't like the CAP theorem because it is vague

Comment: Oops, that leads to a 3rd term.  Well, for MySQL, "cluster" is then the data is stored redundantly in different servers for fault-tolerance or read scaling.

Comment: but it is an replication not sharding. What I am asking is about  InnoDB cluster can split the big data across multi-servers?

Comment: @Harry - "split" as in some rows are on one server, some rows are on another, etc.?

Comment: @Rick yes it is Horizontal sharding

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the idea that you must specify the partition in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM table PARTITION (p1);
```

This is not required. One of the features of partitioning is that if it can infer which partition to read from the logic of your query, it does that automatically.

Suppose your table were partitioned by the `created_at` column. A query that references a specific date in that column would know which partition to access, without you needing to specify it in the table hint syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE created_at = '2020-11-28';
```

Which partition it accesses depends on the way you defined the partitioning when you created the table. But it is deterministic, as long as your search condition references the column used as the partition key. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html to read more about this.

If you run a query that does *not* reference the partition key column, then it cannot make this inference. Say you partitioned by `created_at` but you ran this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 12345;
```

Rows for that `user_id` could occur in any or even all of the partitions. There's no way the partition engine can guess which partitions contain the matching rows without reading the partitions. So that's what it does — it reads *all* of the partitions.

But if you somehow knew that you are only interested in the rows in partition `p1`, that's when you would specify it in your query as you showed.

---

You are correct that InnoDB Cluster does not do sharding for you. All nodes have a copy of all data. It's meant as a solution for redundancy, not scalability.

NDB Cluster isn't for sharding either. All data is stored in the same cluster, but the cluster may have multiple data nodes. But the purpose of NDB having multiple data nodes is not scalability, it's primarily for high availability (HA). As a secondary benefit, it gives you a way to expand storage by adding more nodes.

But if you're not careful about designing your database tables and queries, you might cause it to run queries *slower* than if you stored all data on the same physical node.

I've seen it happen before: a MySQL user designed their database to run on a single node, then some salesperson told them that NDB Cluster is faster, so the user moved their database to NDB Cluster without any regard to matching their tables and queries to the distributed architecture. The result was that their queries have to gather data from every storage node, and their performance degrades.

### This is characteristic of every distributed database architecture.

Sometimes it's referred to as "cross-shard queries" or "fan-out queries." But the basic principle is that you can get scalability only if your query can get its results by visiting only one (or at least a small subset) of the shards. If it has to "fan-out," then you've lost any scalability benefits.

So it requires you design your tables very carefully, keeping in mind the queries you're going to run against the data.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation about partitioning.
but I am actually focused on the cluster and how Partitioning(Sharding) works.